# PHP File Upload No Longer Working, No Changes Made (Plesk Hosting)

Tags: php, file-upload, plesk

I have a web app built with angular and PHP that has been established and running since 2016. There is a file upload feature that will upload a file from client-side app to a directory on the server. I noticed the upload is no longer working. Nothing has changed on our end with the configuration of server/hosting or front-end application. The directory still exists and can successfully list files from the front. I get an internal server error when trying to upload with the code below. Very simple example and nothing to indicate this code no longer works. I have file-uploads = on in the `php.ini` file. It is hosted on GoDaddy. I have checked the error logs and can see that the request is failing but with no detail. Is anyone aware of what may be causing this? I can provide more detail, if thought necessary.

```
<?php
  $target = '../images/attorney_photos/'.$_FILES['file']['name'];
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target);
  print('/assets/images/attorney_photos/'.$_FILES['file']['name']);
?>
```

Comment: What does the error log actually say then?

Comment: It just shows that a request failed with error code 500 but provides no further detail. Perhaps it would be helpful to set up some more detailed error logs, if possible. I see that error logs is turned on in the `php.ini` file but I can't seem to find any actual detailed error descriptions.

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the _error_ log to begin with, and not the _access_ log?

Comment: Please contact your support team, ask them to check full error message on the server. Please be advised 500 error is generic error message.

Answer (score 0):

If your file upload is on then check for

```
upload_max_filesize
```

and

```
post_max_size
```

in your *php.ini* file and also if you want to upload more than a specific limit each request, then check

```
max_file_uploads
```

to be more than files you want upload.

Also it's better to use a tested library for upload your files. you can search for **codeguy/upload** in [packagist](https://packagist.org) and install it with composer for advanced usage or if you no need lots of options you can download this file from [github](https://github.com/aivis/PHP-file-upload-class) that is so simple, easy to use and well written.

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score -1):

login to plesk administrator panel then goto Domain->Website->PHP Settings

Change upload_max_filesize from "2MB" to "16MB"

Save and try uploading again.

Comment: That's only a solution if the problem are the file size... and OP are not telling this.